# How make .qgs files open in QGIS automatically on a Mac?

Tags: qgis

When saving a project my copy of QGIS used to assign file extension .qgis automatically.  Now it assigns .qgs automatically, which means that I can't reopen it.   All my old projects have also been given new extensions .qgs.

Does anyone know what's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

With most computer operating systems, there should be a function to assign a file extension to open with a particular application. This sort of problem is usually an Operating System level problem.

To correct this, as an example on my computer running Mac OS 10.7:

From the File menu -> Open With -> Other...

Browse to your Applications folder and click QGIS. At the bottom of the Window, click the "Always Open With" check box.

Click Open. At this point, all .qgs files should now open with QGIS.

Even if you don't have a Mac, the steps involved are similar with most operating systems. Usually the screen required to make the change is accessible by right clicking on the file.

---

If on a Mac and the above did not work, try running the two following terminal commands:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/QGIS.app
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/QGIS.app
```

(The Terminal application can be found in the Utilities folder. The Utilities folder can be accessed from the Go Menu while in Finder.)

If you have QGIS located in a different spot other than the Applications folder, you will need to adjust the path accordingly. These two commands will unregister all filetype associations then force the Application to re-register them.

Once you have run the second command, you should be able to double click on .qgs files and have them open correctly.

Information courtesy of: http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm on a Mac - but unfortunately it didn't work.  Is it possible that the problem is caused by using Wroclaw 1.7.4 when the old projects were created with 1.7.1?

Comment: I added a portion onto the bottom of my original answer. Try giving that a whirl. I do not know explicitly if any file extension changes occurred though I am very doubtful.

Comment: You may also want to reset 'Launchservices' on your Mac using a utility like Onyx; this removes non-standard links between apps and docs. You can then try the suggestions above again.

Answer (score 2):

using windows the steps are as follws:
right click any projectfile with the extension .qgs and click "open with" and brose to your qgis-folder. select qgis.bat. checkmark box "file-type allways open with selected program!